# R Auto.arima Function - Question About Xreg Covariates

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-encoding

I am using the auto.arima function in R.  I'm using this to forecast daily sales and am loading a number of covariates (mostly holiday/seasonal dummy variables) with Xreg.

Question (I apologize if this question is too fundamental, however, my experience is with regressions on cross sectional data in fixed time periods and I have little experience with dynamic regressions): Using auto.arima, do I still need to exclude a dummy variable from my set of covariates (ie, 6 dummy variables for day of the week instead of 7)?  Is the excluded dummy still caught in the output for the intercept variable?